# Supporting keyboard shortcuts while typing into NSTextView?

Tags: macos

This is more a best practices/usability question around the behavior of MacOS apps.

I have an app where a user is constantly typing into a `NSTextView` (think text editor).

I want to support a few keyboard shortcuts for common tasks within the app so that the user does not need to reach for the mouse to click a button.

But because the user is also typing into a text view, this is a bit tricky figuring out what combinations are available.

- All single character keys are off limits (since the user will actually want to type that character).
- Most cmd+key combinations are also taken (cmd+c, cmd+left, cmd+right, etc).

What's the expected behavior/best practice here?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am in the same boat, I have a menu shortcut `R`, but obviously that would not trigger when the text view is first responder.